# How to set protocol type in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to be able to set the protocol type when I create my CSocket.  As far as I've been able to figure out you can set the second parameter to SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM which respectively is tcp or udp.  So I was wondering if there is a way to use other protocols in the CSocket class in MFC.  Here is my code to receive the connection and data.

```
CSocket sck;
sck.Create(1234, SOCK_STREAM);
sck.Listen();

CSocket clientSck;
sck.Accept(clientSck);
char msg[128];
clientSck.Receive(msg, 128);

CString str;
str = msg;

clientSck.Close();
sck.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [CSocket::Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h61d04c.aspx) only supports `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM` .

Comment: Ok thanks I was just wondering because I know there is a way with c#.